# Azure ARM Template for Queue/Table/File

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I am using below-mentioned ARM template to create a Storage account in Azure but it's creating only blob storage and not queue/table/file.

```
 "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "name": "[variables('storageAccountName')]",
      "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
      "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('storageAccountType')]"
      },
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "Storage"
      },
      "kind": "Storage",
      "properties": {
        "networkAcls": {
          "bypass": "AzureServices",
          "virtualNetworkRules": [],
          "ipRules": [],
          "defaultAction": "Allow"
        },
        "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": true,
        "encryption": {
          "keySource": "Microsoft.Storage",
          "services": {
            "blob": {
              "enabled": true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "storageAccountName": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[variables('storageAccountName')]"
    }
  }
```

Please help in understanding how can I create all storage types using ARM, Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ARM template deploys a Storage Account including blog, files, queues and tables. I tested it using the **Template** Service within the portal and used a slightly modified version:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "storageAccountName": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },

"resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "name": "mystoragggg",
      "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
      "location": "westeurope",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Standard_LRS"
      },
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "Storage"
      },
      "kind": "Storage",
      "properties": {
        "networkAcls": {
          "bypass": "AzureServices",
          "virtualNetworkRules": [],
          "ipRules": [],
          "defaultAction": "Allow"
        },
        "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": true,
        "encryption": {
          "keySource": "Microsoft.Storage",
          "services": {
            "blob": {
              "enabled": true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Proof:

[image]

Comment: This is Generic ARM for creating the Storage account, question is regarding creating table storage/ Queue inside the Storage account

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is possible, there is no documentation on how to do this.

If you want it, vote here: 
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/37651378-allow-to-create-queue-using-arm-template